# Oracle internal date conversion : ORA-00932 and weird stuff

Tags: sql, oracle, date, casting, oracle11gr2

Here many of our developpers are using Oracle hierarchical sub-queries to build lists of days, like this for exemple :

```
WITH mydays AS (
  SELECT CAST( TO_DATE('20161201', 'YYYYMMDD') + ROWNUM AS DATE) AS d
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20161201', 'YYYYMMDD') + ROWNUM <= to_date('20161215', 'YYYYMMDD')
)
```

For me it looked like the CAST ... AS DATE should be useless because we are converting a DATE to a DATE, right ? Actually it is not. If I create and populate a table like this (I need a join for my demonstration...) :

```
create table t(d date, i number);
insert into t(d, i) values (to_date('20161204', 'YYYYMMDD'), 1);
commit;
```

and try a query with a join like that, without the CAST, I get the following explain plan :

```
WITH mydays AS (
  SELECT  TO_DATE('20161201', 'YYYYMMDD') + ROWNUM  AS d
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20161215', 'YYYYMMDD') + ROWNUM <= to_date('20161201', 'YYYYMMDD')
) 
select mydays.d from mydays join t on t.d = mydays.d;
```

.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |      |     1 |    15 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                      |      |     1 |    15 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW                          |      |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    COUNT                        |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL             | T    |     1 |     9 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - access("T"."D"=INTERNAL_FUNCTION("MYDAYS"."D"))
4 - filter(TO_DATE(' 2016-12-15 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
          hh24:mi:ss')+ROWNUM<=TO_DATE(' 2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

with the CAST, the INTERNAL_FUNCTION() is gone :

```
4 - filter(TO_DATE(' 2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
          hh24:mi:ss')+ROWNUM<=TO_DATE(' 2016-12-15 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

I googled a little and found that the conversion should be between two internal date format, handled internally by Oracle  with id 12 and 13, as we can find a call to DUMP(). Without the CAST :

```
Typ=13 Len=8: 7,224,12,4,0,0,0,0
```

With the CAST :

```
Typ=12 Len=7: 120,116,12,4,1,1,1
```

Which explains that we have less conversion with the CAST than without (!!!).

But it get worse when I put bind variables in play. If I want to get the explain plan of this SQL :

```
WITH mydays AS (
  SELECT  TO_DATE(:beginning, 'YYYYMMDD') + ROWNUM  AS d
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY TO_DATE(:end, 'YYYYMMDD') + ROWNUM <= to_date(:beginning, 'YYYYMMDD')
) 
select mydays.d from mydays join t on t.d = mydays.d
```

I get an error : ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER. If I add the CAST magic the error is fixed. I know that when I generate a plan all bind variables are considered as VARCHAR2. But with the TO_DATE(), we should only be working with DATE, right ? Where does this NUMBER come from ?

Thanks if you can give me any explaination, as my brain is beginning to get very messy with all that weird stuff.

Comment: your query was successfully executed without any errors without CAST

Comment: In fact I am working on a more complex query, using that kind of subquery, and it happens that it works 100% of the time in development, and only 99% of the times in production. Oracle uses many explain plans for this query and only one is causing the problem ... and I cannot find which one at the moment.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? The observed behavior (where the "external" date format gives you problems) may be very specific to one particular version. `select * from v$version` may help.

Comment: @jeleb With regards to the `TO_DATE(:beginning, 'yyyymmdd')` what are you passing in to `:beginning`? Is it already of DATE datatype? If so, you don't need the `TO_DATE()`. If you use TO_DATE() on something that's already a DATE, you'll end up doing an implicit conversion, like so: `to_date(to_char(:beginning, '<nls_date_format>'), 'yyyymmdd')` and that may be causing an issue, potentially.

Comment: @Boneist - Bind variables can only be `number` or `(n)(var)char` (various flavors), not `date`. What the OP passes in can only be a `varchar` of some sort.

Comment: @jeleb - I understand why one would want to cast "external dates" to the internal Oracle date format... if you have a table with 10 million rows and your query creates a "calendar" with 1 million dates, you would rather cast 1 million external-format dates to internal format, than have to call INTERNAL_FUNCTION() on an external-format date 10 trillion times. However, I suspect the INTERNAL_FUNCTION() return value is cached and reused in a join, rather than recalculated repeatedly; I doubt that what your developers are doing has any effect on performance. Perhaps it did in older versions?

Comment: @mathguy I'm pretty sure bind variables can be passed in as dates (I do it all the time, in PL/SQL)! I'm aware that some GUI/CLIs won't let you declare a variable as a DATE (SQL*Plus, stand up please!), though - hence why I asked my question.

Comment: @Boneist - good point; I was thinking the OP was passing in the bind variable from a front-end like SQL\*Plus, SQL Developer or Toad, but you are absolutely right, he may be doing that from PL/SQL or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty interest query for getting calendar. Easier to read:

```
SELECT to_date('20160101','yyyymmdd') + LEVEL 
  FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 90;
```

You are looking for solution or just investigating local issue ?

Comment: This post is just to understand what happens. I have a more complex query to deal with, with more than one explicit or implicit conversion issues, and that subquery I need to understand better to be sure I do not miss another one.

Comment: @jeleb - `90` in this solution is a magic number, of course it is easier to read but it is not what the developers needed. With that said, and whether one uses `LEVEL` or `ROWNUM` (they are equivalent), the `CONNECT BY` condition should have `LEVEL` or `ROWNUM` on the left-hand side and a calculation like `to_date(...) - to_date(...)` on the right-hand side. This way, the calculation is "constant" (doesn't change from row to row) so it is performed just once and used repeatedly. The result is a more efficient query.

Comment: @jeleb : So I guess it about implicit conversion of construction "Date + Number" in your select statement with comparing Date field in table. Sometimes Oracle decide this is a number (in this 1%). Mayber it could be usefull https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:67082879150052